# ADFS permission issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, adfs

I configured ADFS on SharePoint 2013, But i got a permission issue

> Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you.

I checked more articles but I can't solve this issue

Any help should be appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to check.

- Make sure you type the correct id( if using the email as login), type the complete email address, there is limitation in people picker. People picker accept everything you type in the field. i.e we use email address as unique identifier, my email address waqas@krossfarm.com but if i type waqas@ or waqas@kross or waqas...system will accept it but wont let you login...you have to type the complete email address...waqas@krossfarm.com.

  - After enabling the ADFS on the Web Application then you have to add the correct user with adfs claim in the site collection.
- Make sure Object cache configured using the proper ADFS claims ids.

Comment: Thanks sir for your answer, but I can't understand these two points  :  - After enabling the ADFS on the Web Application then you have to add the correct user with adfs claim in the site collection. and - Make sure Object cache configured using the proper ADFS claims ids.

Comment: ADFS claim is different for Windows or FBA claims.I.e. i:0#.w for windows, i:05.t|adfs for adfs or i:0#.f|mymembershipprovider ....read this for more information https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13921.sharepoint-20102013-claims-encoding.aspx

Comment: If web application is configured for the Windows Claims then you enable the ADFS than you have to make sure user with correct claims is added...may be you have to move-spuser command to migrate the user from old claim to new.

Comment: the same user have permission with windows authentications , and I configured claims with email , but the user still not resolve the permission of the the same user that have permission ! please help me to trace this issue , it's the first time to configure ADFS :(

Answer (score 0):

I could able to resolve this issue by adding correct user to the site collection administrator. For me, i have a user called spaadmin. when we login to adfs authentication window i used to type spaadmin@wwwww.com.

But when you adding the user , Please check on mouse hover in sitesettings adding site collection admnistrator , for this single user, i have 16 different names in site collection administration text area. like spa for email, spa for UPN, spa for ADFSGroup, spa admin, spaadmin. And finally i had added spaadmin@wwwww.com (UPN for my identity (default it will be email in all cases, but for us it is UPN mapped in security token issuer) mouse hover) had resolved my issue.